# Installing numpy on openshift origin

Tags: django, numpy, openshift, openshift-origin

I am trying to install numpy on openshift so that my django website can access it. I tried to install it by calling `pip install numpy` in the pod terminal. This seemed to install but when I tried to import numpy in my code it gave `ImportError: No module named numpy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the OpenShift S2I builder for Python, you would be pointing it at your repository with your application source code. That repo should have a `requirements.txt` file in it which lists the names of the Python packages you want installed. So create that file and add `numpy` to it and then trigger a new build and deployment of your application.

If you are not using the Python S2I builder, you need to explain how you are running your application under OpenShift.